# Convert string datetime to timestamp (with literal months) SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to cast the following string to timestamp in pyspark:

```
"30-Jun-2022 14:00:00"
```

I've tried the following approaches:

```
f.col("date_string").cast("timestamp"),

f.to_timestamp(f.col("date_string")).alias("date_string") ,

.withColumn(
         "date_string",
         f.to_timestamp(f.col("date_string")
)
```

But all of them return a `null` column, what am I doing wrong?

MVCE:

```
 data = [
 ("30-Jun-2022 14:00:00"),
("25-Jul-2022 11:00:00"),
("10-May-2022 12:00:00"),
("11-Jan-2022 09:00:00")
 ]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("date_string", StringType(),True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a testing environment for pyspark, but in Spark, this:

```
.withColumn("timestamped",to_timestamp(col("name"), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

returns this (which I assume is what you want):

```
name,timestamped
30-Jun-2022 14:00:00,2022-06-30 14:00:00
```